# Twitter API Problem iPad 

Tags: iphone, sdk, ipad

iam using TwitterRequest API for my ipad app's twitter client ! but i don't know why application going to crash after user tap the tweet button  and debugger doesn't detect any bug !!!! 
i use this tutorial :

http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/

but it seems doesn't work on SDK 4.0! any solution ? thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Try running you application with the debugger and single step through the code that is executed when the user taps the button.

Once you have located the exact line that causes the crash, it should be possible to narrow down the reason by inspecting variables, etc.

Comment: The debugger detects EXC_BAD_ACCESS ! what can i do ?